# Unstable DC dummy load

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, dc

I have built a breadboard prototype of the following dummy load schematic:

[image]

however, neither the current stays stable nor the potentiometer adjustment to vary the current is working as was expected. I have done three modifications to the original circuit by:

1. using 9v dc from a wall AC-DC adapter instead of supplying 12V DC and a voltage regulator
2. removing the 1N4004 diode and the capacitors

I wonder is my circuit unstable due to above changes and/or the breadboard is also contributing to the problem.

Replacing the 1.5 ohm with a 1 ohm resistor didn't make a difference. I have also tried using a 2 x 100nf and a 10uf cap on the power rails but it still doesn't work. After triple checking the connections and building the circuit again from scratch I am unable to solve the issue on my own.

So could you please help me figure out the problem?

EDIT
Here is my actual circuit

[image: My Circuit]

I rebuilt my circuit again and now I am reading around 0.6 A flowing in the circuit that is very slowly going down (like 0.001 A per second). Some other measurements that I have done are as follows:

Power supply voltage : 9.19 V
Mosfet V+ : 9.19 V
Mosfet Out1 : 0 V
Mosfet Out2 : 5.65 V
Vgs = 5.65 V
Vds = 0.012 V

Now adjusting the variable resistors isn't having any effect on the current value. Getting more and more weird :(

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Can you define unstable with an oscillogram of both input and output voltage showing?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope. I am just using a DMM to measure the current running through the circuit.

Comment: "*using 9v dc instead of 7809*" is this source a 9V battery?

Comment: Consider getting one. For switch mode, it’s a must. For linear you may get by without one unless you have oscillations...

Comment: The many rows of contacts and wires all over the place on a breadboard pickup all kinds of interference causing instability. Also the breadboard contacts are usually intermittent. Solder a compact circuit on a pcb or on a piece of stripboard.

Comment: I have added the circuit diagram of my modified circuit as well as some readings at different points.

Comment: When the MOSFET has 12mV Vds it’s doing about as much as it can (and more than you should expect) to increase the current.. do you understand how that works?

Comment: If I am not mistaken then a very low Vds means that the mosfet is fully conducting. What I don't understand is the effect of variable resistors. Ideally adjusting them would change Vgs and thus the Vds and the current flowing in the circuit. But it seems like they are not working at all

Answer (score 3):

Probably your circuit is oscillating. Since you don't have an oscilloscope, you can try measuring the op-amp output on the AC range of a multimeter. Also check the supply rail and verify that reads close to zero (most multimeters will read zero for a DC input on an AC range).

If so, the solution is to decouple the heavy capacitive load of the MOSFET gate/1 ohm resistor using a series resistor and separate the AC feedback path from the DC.

Typically something like this will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhPvZ6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also keep in mind that your current sink only has so much compliance. At 2A, for example, there is 2V nominally across the sense resistor, which means the MOSFET has that much less to work with, and worse the 2V has reduced Vgs by 2V, and as you know the LM358 cannot output the full supply voltage so there may not be enough voltage to turn on the IRF540 sufficiently if the load voltage is too low.

If your current is not constant, but rather drops steadily with decreasing load voltage, this would be a likely cause.

Comment: I did some AC Voltage measurements and the got 0.008 V on the power rails, mosfet output 1 & 2.

Comment: I tried to decouple the capacitive load as you proposed but the current starts at 200mA and gradually goes down like you mentioned. Regarding the working voltage for the mosfet, the current never went up more than 200mA and so the voltage drop across the 1 Ohm resistor also is low ~ 0.2V.

Comment: The MOSFET does needs voltage across it (Vds) to control the current. If it gets too low, the MOSFET can do no more.

Answer (score 0):

The LM358 is a relatively old design and has awful crossover distortion; I suspect that this is causing the instability.  You could try using a smaller value for R5 to ensure that the IC is always driving in one direction and never enters the crossover region, otherwise consider using a better op amp such as a TL082.  There may be other things you’ll need to do but I’d suggest dealing with that first.

Comment: I tried 100 Ohm resistor for R5 but the current steadily goes down from. Unfortunately I only have LM358 but I will order different one to see if that shows a different behavior.